# Backbone model save state

Tags: php, javascript, rest, backbone.js

I use backbone model to save the data to the server. then I handle the success or error callback after save(post) and set wait:true. my question is why backbone model only trigger the error callback when server returns a string? when server returns a json or any number, it will go to the success. the problem is if I want to return a multiple error message and I want to put all error message into a collection(json), it will never go to error callback. sample code like

```
echo 'success'; //actually it will go to error callback cuz it return a string(any string)
echo json_encode($some_array); // it will go to success
echo 200/anynumber; // it will go to sucess
```

My solution is if I wanna return a multiple message, I can separate those message by a delimiter, and use javascript native function split to separate them. is there any better solution like maybe I can return a state(indicate either success or error) and a collection from server?

```
model code looks like:
somemodel.save({somedata},
    {
        success:function(a,b,c){}, 
        error:function(b,c,d){},
        wait: true
    });
```

Comment: Can you show your code for the model?

Comment: @eded Please check my last edit to the answer, as i have done most tests and added a new piece of code. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone expects JSON as the default response format. <strike>When you get an integer, i suspect, backbone is using jquery `$.parseJSON()` on the number and returns it as valid JSON while it is not.</strike>
If you want to return multiple errors messages, i suggest you put them into separate fields of an array and encode them then send as response to backbone.

#### EDIT

Just checked backbone source code and it doesn't call on `$.parseJOSN()` contrary to what was guessed above.

#### EDIT 2

Assume you have the following PHP code (as much as I would like to create a framework agnostic example, it is possible but things will be quicker and smoother using a framework so I have picked [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)).

When you save a model, backbone sends the data to the server using POST as the method. In Slim this will translate into the following:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->post('/authors/', function() use($app) {
    // We get the request data from backbone in $request
    $request = $app->request()->getBody();
    // We decode them into a PHP object
    $requestData = json_decode($request);
    // We put the response object in $response : this will allow us to set the response data like header values, etc
    $response = $app->response();

    // You do all the awesome stuff here and get an array containing data in $data //

    // Sample $data in case of success
    $data = array(
        'code' => 200,
        'status' => 'OK',
        'data' => array('id'=>1, 'name' => 'John Doe')
    );

    // sample $data in case of error
    $data = array(
        'code' => 500,
        'status' => 'Internal Server Error',
        'message' => 'We were unable to reach the data server, please try again later'
    );

    // Then you set the content type
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    // Don't forget to add the HTTP code, Backbone.js will call "success" only if it has 2xx HTTP code
    $app->response()->status( $data['code']);
    // And finally send the data
    $response->write($data);
```

I have used Slim simply because it gets the job done and everything should read like English.

As you can see, Backbone will need the response in JSON format. I just tested on one of my websites, if you send an HTTP code different from 2xx, Backbone will actually call `error` instead of `success`. But the browser will also catch that HTTP code, so watch out!

**REMOVED INFO**

Backbone `parse` function will be expecting JSON as well!
Assume we have this collection:

```
var AuthorsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function( models, options ) {
        this.batch = options.batch
    },

    url: function() {
        return '/authors/' + this.batch;
    },

    // Parse here allows us to play with the response as long as "response" is a JSON object. Otherwise, Backbone will automatically call the "error" function on whatever, say view, is using this collection.
    parse: function( response ) {
        return response.data;
    }
});
```

`parse` allows you to inspect the response, but will not accept anything else than JSON!

Comment: the problem is when I use json_encode to any array, it will always go to success callback. even it is a json string. only regular string will fall to error

Comment: @eded Yes, backbone will call `error` only if it received the wrong format for the response. If it gets the proper response, it will go to `success`. Personally I use HTTP codes to determine if i have an error or a success and act on that. If backbone calls `error`, then i know whatever I sent was not JSON and my code is sending the wrong response. Think of `error` as a function that helps you debug the server response. Hope it has better use than that!

Comment: @ntbas thanks for explaining that. i will really appriciate if you can show me some sample code or any short examples